# how to package Java app (.jar) for windows store using visual studio 2015

Tags: java, visual-studio

Beginners problem.

I am trying to package my .jar program for windows store. I have installed visual studio 2015 but not sure what direction to go in next. Simple step by step tutorial seem thin on the ground.
Any help gratefully recieved.

Comment: Sorry forgot to say I have turned my original .jar file into a Windows .exe file.

Comment: I have my windows executable file loaded into visual studio 2015 but it does not have any options to package for store. The options in the main menu are greyed out and when I right click the file in the solution explorer it does not have the same options as I have seen in tutorials.